# Index Match a date within a quarter data set

Tags: excel, indexing, match

I have data sets specific for each quarter within a tab where I need to find the day and suffix matching the date. ie the date I need to match too maybe in one of several columns and the results I want to the right of that date. I've used index match instead of `Vlookup()` before but the multiple column thing is where I'm not sure

[image]

Comment: Convert the date you're looking up to its corresponding quarter and do a match on the row with the quarter headers. From there you should be able to match the specific date in the appropriate column, and return the suffix.

Answer (score 0):

There are various ways of doing this, but a fairly short one is to do the match on the quarter as suggested by @BigBen, then use Index to get a reference to the top of the starting column for the list of dates for the quarter. Then use vlookup to get the value in the third column relative to the starting column:

```
=VLOOKUP(Q2,INDEX($A$3:$P$3,MATCH(TEXT(Q2,"yy")&"Q"&ROUNDUP(MONTH(Q2)/3,0),$A$1:$P$1,0)):$P$100,3,FALSE)
```

[image]

Note: FALSE can be omitted from the vlookup because the dates are in ascending order but it it is better to include it so that you get #N/A if the date input is a holiday or weekend.

Comment: And now after discussions the data set only had to be the current quarter due to being able to be produced by formulas reducing the complexity of the issue. Now its a simple query :)